Delete documents from a TimeSeries collection based on non-metadata element
I want to delete all documents with timestamp after "17-06-2024 23h59", BUT my timestamp is outside the "metadata" field. Example one of my document :
{
  "ts": {
    "$date": "2021-03-24T19:40:00.000Z"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "sensorsId": "whatever"
  },
  "locationUUID": "whatever",
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "whatever"
  },
  "data": {
    "temperature": {"$numberDecimal": "21.4"}
    }
}

Here's my code :
filter_criteria = {'timestamp': {'$gt': datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 17,23,59)}}
documents = collection.find(filter_criteria)
document_ids = [doc['_id'] for doc in documents]
results = sensors_comfort.delete_many({'_id': {'$in': document_ids}})

But i got this error :
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot perform an update or delete on a time-series collection when querying on a field that is not the metaField 'metadata', full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 72, 'errmsg': "Cannot perform an update or delete on a time-series collection when querying on a field that is not the metaField 'metadata'"}


The issue cannot be reproduced. Metadata should be "kind of" independent from timestamp field. Also, why don't you simply do a deleteMany with your criteria?

I got the same issued even with the filter_criteria inside the deletaMany. What do you need to reproduce ?

I upgraded mongodb from 5.x to 7.1 and now it's possible to do so. Fixed

I have the same problem for update_many in mongo 7. But I can do delete_many.
Is this behavior expected or do you believe I am doing something wrong?
